# IE10 compatibility mode handles onpropertychange wrong

Tags: javascript, validation, internet-explorer-10, propertychanged, compatibility-mode

I am using some JS events to track changes on an HTML input field because I need to validate the input.

```
$("#field").bind("propertychange keyup input paste",  function() { ValidateFunction('field'); }); }
```

Everyting works pretty fine, but IE10 in compatibility mode goes crazy because of the propertychanged event. Once this is triggered, IE is not useable any longer. 
When I remove propertychange from the event-list, IE is useable but I do not catch all events (e.g. cut actions or when I mark text and move it out of the input field).

Update: There are stack overflow exceptions shown in the error console.

The combination of these 4 events works fine in other browsers i need to support, including normal IE10.

Are there known workarounds for this problem? I couldn't find a way to track every kind of user input without this event yet.

thanks & br

Comment: It freezes and the error console shows a lot of stack overflow exceptions. Sorry for not mentioning that...

Comment: Is the validation code changing the content of the input?

Comment: No, it changes the class of the input field. The value stays the same. Propertychanged is triggered because of this for sure, but I don't see a way how to prevent this...